# responsive side navigation menu with hamburger icon

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

[simple menu header when not opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwA2N.jpg)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function toggleSidebar() {
    $(".button").toggleClass("active");
    $("main").toggleClass("move-to-left");
    $(".sidebar-item").toggleClass("active");
  }

  $(".button").on("click tap", function() {
    toggleSidebar();
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      toggleSidebar();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,400italic,700,700italic);
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
}

main {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2D3142;
  -webkit-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #EF8354;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #EF8354;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}

.nav-right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  top: 20px;
}

.nav-right.visible-xs {
  z-index: 3;
}

.hidden-xs {
  display: none;
}

.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bar {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}

.nav-right.visible-xs .active .bar {
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}

.button.active .top {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: translateY(15px) rotateZ(45deg);
}

.button.active .bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-15px) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.button.active .middle {
  width: 0;
}

.move-to-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-400px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-400px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-400px);
  transform: translateX(-400px);
}

nav {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.sidebar-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar-item {
  margin: 30px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}

.sidebar-item:first-child {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item:last-child {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.sidebar-anchor {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.sidebar-anchor:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-anchor:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}

.ua {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 60px;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #EF8354;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.ua:hover .fa {
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-right {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .hidden-xs {
    display: block;
  }
  .visible-xs {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="nav-right visible-xs">
  <div class="button" id="btn">
    <div class="bar top"></div>
    <div class="bar middle"></div>
    <div class="bar bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- nav-right -->
<main>


  <nav>
    <img src="http://safindia.org/assets/img/logohome.png" class="img-responsive">
     <div class="nav-right hidden-xs">
      <div class="button" id="btn">
        <div class="bar top"></div>
        <div class="bar middle"></div>
        <div class="bar bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- nav-right -->
  </nav>

  <a href="https://codepen.io/tonkec/" class="ua" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </a>
</main>

<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="sidebar-list">
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">What We Do</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Get Involved</a></li>
     <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
</div>
```

hello the above code is for side navigation bar.it works fine for me but the problem i am facing is when i click on the hamburger icon it pull or slide my main section to the left side.i don't want to slide my background content or main content to be slide left side & my close button is to be display on right side of menu body section.but it display outside or aside of the menu bar.as well i want to make my menu shrink or resize on page scroll.[menu design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXK8L.jpg)

Comment: So, you want to show the menu list on clicking the hamburger with the close button right?  you have two different buttons with same ids.

Comment: yes i want to as displayed in the image u can check the image by clicking "menu design" it will display you the image what i actually want

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- nav-right -->
<main>


  <nav>
    <img src="http://safindia.org/assets/img/logohome.png" class="img-responsive">
     <div class="nav-right hidden-xs">
      <div class="button" id="btn">
        <div class="bar top"></div>
        <div class="bar middle"></div>
        <div class="bar bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- nav-right -->
  </nav>

  <a href="https://codepen.io/tonkec/" class="ua" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </a>
</main>

<div class="sidebar">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" id="close-button" style="color: white;font-size: 30px;"></span>

  <ul class="sidebar-list"> 
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">What We Do</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Get Involved</a></li>
     <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-anchor">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
</div>
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,400italic,700,700italic);
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
}

main {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2D3142;
  -webkit-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;   
  right: 0;
  background-color: #EF8354;
  display:none;
      z-index: 3;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #EF8354;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}

.nav-right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  top: 20px;
}

#btn-close {
  z-index: 3;
}

.hidden-xs {
  display: none;
}

.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bar {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}

#btn-close .active .bar {
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}



nav {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.sidebar-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar-item {
  margin: 30px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}

.sidebar-item:first-child {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .4s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item:last-child {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s .6s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-item {
  opacity: 3;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.sidebar-anchor {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.sidebar-anchor:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-anchor:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}

.ua {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 60px;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #EF8354;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.ua:hover .fa {
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-right {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .hidden-xs {
    display: block;
  }
  #btn-close{
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#btn").on("click", function() { 
  $(this).hide();
    $(".sidebar").css('display','block');
 
  });
$("#close-button").on("click", function() { 

 $('#btn').show();
  $(".sidebar").css('display','none');
  });
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
     
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

This is what you asked for? I have added close glyphicon instead of button.Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: no its not like that it should be same but close button is diplaying aside of menu it should display as displayed in image and the main content is pull to left side it should be constant it dont pull or slide

Comment: Did you run the above codes?  The main content is not pulled to the left side and it s constant.I cannot see the image,it has been restricted.

Comment: nothing displayed its not even working i want to make working this menu for all screen sizes. its only work for full screen

Comment: copy the codes and run it,It was working fine for me.